# Is there any equivalent of SQLBulkCopy in TeraData

Tags: teradata, sqlbulkcopy

After some goоgling, I could not find a proper replacement of SQLBulkCopy from SQLClient in TeraData. Can any body suggest me anything like SQLBulkCopy for TeraData to be used in c#? I need to insert up-to a few millions of rows in TD
Need this to compare a set a rows retrieved from external DB and dumped into TD and compare with data already available in TeraData.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find an equivalent but this is acceptably fast for my purposes. Also I suspect that the UpdateBatchSize could be tweaked to match your particular data to increase speeds.

As written, your source and destination tables must have the same columns (like BulkCopy, although not necessarily in the same order).

```
TdConnection tdCon = new TdConnection(tdConString);
SqlConnection sqlCon1 = new SqlConnection(serverOneConString);

// Get schema for destination table
var query = "SELECT * FROM [Destination_Table] where 0 = 1";
using (TdDataAdapter insertAdapter = new TdDataAdapter(query, tdCon))
{
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     insertAdapter.Fill(ds);

     // Load data from source table
     using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Source_Table]", sqlCon1)) {
         dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240;
         dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
     }                

     // Move data from source to destination, matching column names
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
         var newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
         foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
             newRow[column.ColumnName] = row[column.ColumnName];
         }
         ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
     }
     TdCommandBuilder builder = new TdCommandBuilder(insertAdapter);
     insertAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = 250;
     insertAdapter.Update(ds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Teradata's .Net provider can be used for loading, you need to set TdDataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize as high as possible, at least a few hundred.

If this is not fast enough for larger amounts of data you might switch to Teradata's [TPT-API](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2516_034K/2516ch01.049.02.html)

Comment: Do you have any coding example on how to use TdDataAdapter to add a large dataset to Teradata in c#? Could not find any good where they use TdDataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize and add a large dataset to the database.

Comment: I'm not a C# developer, but any example using the base DataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize should work.

Comment: Ok I will search, Thx for your time anyhow.